# Error in the layout for displaying the listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to use a list view and I have created my own layout for displaying the data in the list view. Here is my code:

```
public class ListActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" };

        // First paramenter - Context
        // Second parameter - Layout for the row
        // Third parameter - ID of the View to which the data is written
        // Forth - the Array of data
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
//#1            android.R.layout.list_item, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

//list_item is a layout that I created which contains a text view and size

```
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

But on line #1 I am getting an error

```
list_item connot be resolved or is not a field
```

I have also created the list_item.xml file as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp">


</TextView>
```

Where am I going wrong? 
Got the Answer from @ByteMe. Now there is no error.But I am getting the following error on runtime. I copied the logcat contents and this is what I am getting:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  384): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught e
xception
E/AndroidRuntime(  384): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromRes
ource(ArrayAdapter.java:353)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdap
ter.java:323)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsList
View.java:1274)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildr
en(ListView.java:1147)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.ja
va:1060)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargin
s(ViewGroup.java:3023)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBefor
eLayout(LinearLayout.java:888)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(L
inearLayout.java:350)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearL
ayout.java:278)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargin
s(ViewGroup.java:3023)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLay
out.java:245)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(L
inearLayout.java:464)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearL
ayout.java:278)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargin
s(ViewGroup.java:3023)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLay
out.java:245)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewR
oot.java:763)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.
java:1633)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.ja
va:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThrea
d.java:4363)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:5
21)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndA
rgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygot
eInit.java:618)
E/AndroidRuntime(  384):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I/Process (   59): Sending signal. PID: 384 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  384): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(  384): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

What is the problem now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.list_item, R.id.text1, values);
```

instead of

```
android.R.layout.list_item
```

that seemed to fix it for me

Comment: Your suggestion has removed the error. But now I am getting a runtime error in log cat. The first line in logcat says that "threadid=3 thread exiting with uncaught exception."

Answer (score 0):

Since no one is answering the second part of the question(the first part of the question was answered by @ByteMe), I will answer the question myself(got the answer after going through list view basics). The anser is quite simple.
Just remove the optional parameter(third parameter) from the Adapter constructor.